# Why can't a query using 2 CTEs be linked to another table

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

I have something similar to the code below.  I'm new to Oracle. It works fine until I try to join it to "anothertable" then states it can't see cte2.a.  I can't find anything that explains why it can't see cte2.a
I need the data created by cte2 to further my query.  Should i just do that inside of cte2 instead?

WITH cte 1 as (......),
cte2 as (....join tablename on tablename.x = cte1.x)
select *
from cte2
join anothertable on anothertable.a = cte2.a

---

---

Here is the actual query.  It states "MAX_HEM"."PATIENT_ID":  invalid identifier

```
    WITH HGB AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           PH.PATIENT_ID, 
           PH.HEMATOLOGY_CD, --EX HGB
           PH.PATIENT_HEMATOLOGY_ID,
           PH.HEMATOLOGY_RESULT, 
           PH.TRANSACTION_DATE,
           PH.TRANSACTION_TIME,
           (TO_CHAR(PH.TRANSACTION_DATE) || ' ' ||      (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(PH.TRANSACTION_TIME,4,'0'),'HH24MI'),'HH:MI AM'))) AS HGB_DATETIME,
           TO_NUMBER(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM(TO_CHAR(ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME,'HH24MI')))) AS ISSUE_TIME,  
           ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME || ' ' || (TO_CHAR(ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME, 'HH:MI AM')) AS ISSUE_DTTM, 
           PRODUCT_INVENTORY.UNIT_NO,
           CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE
          
           FROM   
           PRODUCT_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY PRODUCT_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY 
            
           JOIN CD_TRANSACTION CD_TRANSACTION ON PRODUCT_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY.TRANSACTION_CD = CD_TRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_CD
           AND (CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='TA' OR CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='TX' OR CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='IE') 
             
           JOIN ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY ON PRODUCT_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY.PRODINV_ID = ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.PRODINV_ID
                         
           JOIN ORDERS ORDERS ON ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
             
           JOIN PATIENT_HEMATOLOGY PH ON PH.PATIENT_ID = ORDERS.PATIENT_ID
             
           JOIN CD_ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT CD_ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT ON ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT_CD = CD_ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT.ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT_CD
            
           JOIN PRODUCT_INVENTORY PRODUCT_INVENTORY ON ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.PRODINV_ID = PRODUCT_INVENTORY.PRODINV_ID 
            
           WHERE PH.HEMATOLOGY_CD = 'HGB'            
           AND PH.TRANSACTION_DATE <= TRUNC(ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME)
           AND PH.TRANSACTION_TIME <= TO_NUMBER(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM(TO_CHAR(ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME,'HH24MI'))))
           AND  CD_ORDER_PRODUCT_INV_STAT.WTCODE='TRANSFUSED' 
           AND (CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='TA' OR CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='TX' OR CD_TRANSACTION.WTCODE='IE') 
           AND ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME IS  NOT  NULL 
           AND (ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME>=TO_DATE ('01-09-2020 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
           AND ORDER_PRODUCT_INVENTORY.ISSUE_DATETIME<TO_DATE ('06-09-2020 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
           ORDER BY PH.PATIENT_ID, UNIT_NO,TO_DATE(PH.TRANSACTION_DATE) DESC, PH.TRANSACTION_TIME DESC
           ),
MAX_HEM AS
(
  SELECT 
       HGB.PATIENT_ID "PatID",
       MAX(HGB.PATIENT_HEMATOLOGY_ID) "HemID",
       MAX(HGB.TRANSACTION_DATE) "TransDate",
       MAX(HGB.TRANSACTION_TIME) "TransTime",
       MAX(HGB.HEMATOLOGY_RESULT) "HGB_Results",
       MAX(HGB.UNIT_NO) "UnitNo"
         
  FROM PATIENT_HEMATOLOGY PH1
  LEFT JOIN HGB ON PH1.PATIENT_ID = HGB.PATIENT_ID
  GROUP BY HGB.PATIENT_ID
  ORDER BY HGB.PATIENT_ID
  )

select 
      HGB.*,
      MAXHEM.*
FROM MAX_HEM
LEFT JOIN ORDERS ORDERS ON ORDERS.PATIENT_ID = MAX_HEM.PATIENT_ID
```

Comment: Please provide actual query. It is quite difficult to guess the error based on your question.

Comment: Since you aliased PATIENT_ID in the MAX_HEM CTE, you must reference that alias instead of the original column name. Try using `MAX_HEM."PatID"` instead. Although you may also want to reconsider using double quotes because now you're going to have them all over the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below and its working for me. Just check is it something like this you are expecting?

```
WITH cte AS
 ( select 'a' as a from dual 
 union
 select 'g' as a from dual
  ), cte2 AS
 (select 'a' as b from dual
 union
 select 'c' as b from dual
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte c inner JOIN cte2 c2 ON c.a = c2.b
```

Comment: I've attached my original code block.  Just not seeing what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your are using ORDERS table in the join condition  with MAX_HEM, and  HGB is not joined anywhere.  If you want to use ORDERS  then bring that also into a CTE expression  then try to join with MAX_HEM. Can you try and tell if you are facing any issue?

Comment: Ok, i see your point.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! If its good and solved your problem then kindly mark the answer as completed so that for someone else this could be helpful :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your query works:

```sql
WITH cte1 (x) as (
  SELECT dummy FROM DUAL
),
cte2 (x, a) as (
  SELECT tablename.x,
         tablename.a
  FROM   cte1
         join tablename
         on tablename.x = cte1.x
)
select *
from   cte2
       join anothertable
       on anothertable.a = cte2.a;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename ( x, a ) AS
SELECT dummy, ROWNUM FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE anothertable ( a ) AS
SELECT ROWNUM FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> X  |  A |  A
> :- | -: | -:
> X  |  1 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7b13ca89acacce973009abb072f12ef)*